# Creating request scope by passing object among all threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, thread-local, thread-local-storage

The system receives a request R. Then we create a unique object "tracker". We want to use tracker associated with R if the current code is processing request R or any of the runnables that help complete it.

The access is tough if the system has multiple classes using multiple threads. So I am trying to work on framework for that.

So, along with ThreadLocal, ThreadPoolExecutor has something called beforeExecute and submit methods that can help me achieve this ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable) )

However the issue is that then i restrict everyone to use executors or threads from my framework which i would like to avoid.

Comment: Thread-local among all threads is basically a contradiction in terms. I suggest you rethink all this. You're using a hammer to peel a grape.

Comment: @EJP perhaps i shouldnt use thread local word but idea is that all the work done (in any of the class or thread ) due to some request in some class/thread should be able to access some common object.. each of this object is unique to this request..

Comment: @EJP i have rephrased the question. Since im using thread local as part of solution, i mentioned it in the first place.

Comment: To solve your problem you need to understand that a `Thread` never does "starting and stoping any task/runnable/callable". A `Thread` upon calling it's start method will run it's `run` method exactly once. Everything else is done in `ThreadPoolExecutor` and other `Executor`s

Comment: @ThomasKläger yes, and m looking for rich information like when it starts running or stop and which runnable. assuming the threads are from same process and can be created independently

Comment: Well, the only notification that the JVM itself gives about thread start/stop are through the JVMTI interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#ThreadStart). The only other level of notification I know about is from the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You can code it yourself - but either way (extending `ThreadPoolExecutor` or your own pool implementation) your customers are tied to your implementation.

Comment: thanks @ThomasKläger

Comment: Give every request an unique ID, store it in request. Write thread-safe singleton class with Map<requestID, tracker> or use synchronizedMap. Access tracker with requestID.Tracker must be thread-safe or immutable.

Comment: @doge one might have lot of classes like at dao level who would not be requestId aware and wont like to insert it everywhere..

Comment: Then one must have current requestID bind to the thread and update it every time new request processing starts.

Comment: yes and to achieve it currently i m forcing everyone to use my threads rather than any arbitrary thread so i wanted to know if there is a way to allow arbitrary threads